# How to use jinja to generate xml file on GAE?

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, jinja2

I know how to use `jinja2` to generate html pages as response to urls on GAE ( https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates).

I need to use `jinja2` to create an actual xml file and save it on my server.

An example of someone using a tool called `util` is at http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-engine-part-9-Sitemaps-and-review or https://github.com/Arachnid/bloggart/blob/part9/static.py (on line 47).

A snippet of the UTIL example (never mind he is creating a sitemap):

```
rendered = utils.render_template('sitemap.xml', {'paths': paths})
set('/sitemap.xml', rendered, 'application/xml', False)
```

Can `Jinja2` do something like that?

I have tried many things, including the following:

```
data = jinja_environment.get_template('for_xml.html')
fo = open("/myfile.xml","w+")
fo.write(data)
fo.close()
```

So far whether I use `w+` or `wb` I get an error:

```
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 632, in __init__
raise IOError('invalid mode: %s' % mode)
IOError: invalid mode: w+
```

When I use `set` as in the `UTIL` example, it says `set` needs 1 parameter not 4.

Answer (score 3):

Google app engine sandbox will not allow you to write to the file system. -- Take a look at *The Sandbox* section [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine?hl=en).

The sitemap example you cited shall be creating a XML response to the client.

Comment: Thanks. I am taking a break. Maybe I can see better what he is doing to auto create his `sitemap.xml` on the fly later. Many thanks. Up vote.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a file to GAE server, you can however write a file to either [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore) or [Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/). See the apis, as they provide some File-like object to write to.

ps: when using set you are getting an error, because it refers to the function that user defined and I guess in your code you are not including that definition, so you are in fact using the set constructor which takes only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you need a dynamic sitemap, why not create it on the fly.
Second: With Jinja2 you also can use XML templates = read XML templates and NOT ONLY html.

Conslusion: create a non static handler with serves the dynamic creation of the "sitemap.xml" and jinja will render your sitemap.xml result.